# Python/Numpy Creating Datasets from Known Frequencies

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any functionality to create numpy arrays or other similar data structures from known frequencies?  I am looking at a dataset that has frequencies for 5 coins being tossed 1000 times below.

Number of Heads -

0 - 38,
1 - 144,
2 - 342,
3 - 287,
4 - 164,
5 - 25,

It would be relatively simple for using a list comprehension or the like

[0 for i in range(38)]...

Creating each of these and then merging them all to create the original data set is relatively easy for the data above.

I was wondering if there is an existing shortcut to do this if this were to require much larger numbers i.e. 10 million tosses or more coins say 10 thousand and make manual entry an effort.  This assumes we already have the data available in a tabular form.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of shortcut you expect. But one way to do it in plain python would be:

```
freq = {0:38, 1:144, 2:342, 3:287, 4:164, 5:25}
[h for h, n in sorted(freq.items()) for _ in range(n)]
```

And to do it with numpy, you could do:

```
np.hstack([np.full(n, h) for h, n in sorted(freq.items())])
```

Or the fastest way without any comprehension:

```
a = np.empty(sum(freq.values()))
i = 0
for h,n in sorted(freq.items()):
    a[i:][:n] = h
    i += n
```

Comment: Something like converter.FreqToArray(val, freq).  This way I could act and query the data as if all the values were held but without the overhead of creating and/or storing them

Comment: @EnE_ so basically you are looking for a data structure that stores range-value pairs and if you index it, it looks up the range in which the index falls and gives you the corresponding value? That is certainly possible but I don't know of any implementation. Having a complete numpy array makes things easier though. By the way 10 million tosses is just 10 million times 4 bytes which is 40Mb... no problem for a machine with more than 1Gb memory which I bet you have.